# How to get keyCode in froala

Tags: jquery, froala

having problem on geting the keyCode on keypress on froala editor 
this is the code froala propose for on keypress

```
 $('#editor1').on('froalaEditor.keypress', function (e, editor, keypressEvent) {
alert(e.keyCode);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/szpfw12c/#fork 
i get undefined. thank you for the help!

Comment: thx for the reply,i added it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution

use keypressEvent to get keycode ( not e )

```
$('.edit').froalaEditor()
$('.edit').on('froalaEditor.keypress', function (e, editor, keypressEvent){
    alert(keypressEvent.which);
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/szpfw12c/1/)

Comment: hi sir i stil have  a problem they keys i wanted to get are shift and enter so i can do a condition ,but when i press on enter it doesnt show anything... help plz

Comment: i got it i wil use on key up

Answer (score 0):

If you find information about events look

https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/events